# Winsock Server Client Ejemplo

Tags: c++

Buenas,
Como trabajo en la uni, nos han mandado hacer un programilla con un servidor y un cliente. Pero para ello nos han dicho que primero tenemos que hacer funcionar un ejemplo de servidor y cliente. Nos han dado el ejemplo asi, con estos 2 códigos.

Servidor:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx

Cliente: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx

Lo que he hecho ha sido meter abrir un proyecto y he metido cada código(el del cliente y el servidor) en un archivo: server.cpp y client.cpp

Y después de arreglar un problema que había con los headers me he atascado con estos 2 errores:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2005 _main already defined in
>   client.obj    BAAER2  D:\DDocumentos\BAAER2\BAAER2\BAAER2\server.obj  1

y

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols
>   found BAAER2  D:\DDocumentos\BAAER2\BAAER2\Debug\BAAER2.exe   1

El primero creo que tiene con que tengo 2 archivos con main pero no estoy seguro de cómo arreglarlo.

PD: El profesor dijo que había que añadir o pasar como argumento localhost(127.0.0.1), con click derecho propiedades... pero no me acuerdo mucho más, ¿sabéis también esto?

Comment: Parece que debes compilar los dos archivos por separado, de forma que te quedaran dos ejecutables. Lo cual es lógico pues tendrías por un lado el servidor y por otro el cliente

Comment: como puedo compilarlos por separado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea dos proyectos diferentes uno llamado, cliente y el otro servidor. Pon cada uno de los fuentes en uno de estos proyectos diferentes. Ambos proyectos deberán enlazar la librería `ws_32.lib` quien provee los métodos de winsock2.

Luego compilas los proyectos y corres el servidor primero.

Finalmente, corres el ciente desde la linea de comandos así: (debes buscar donde dejo el compilador el archivo .exe)

```
C:\Path\al\cliente> cliente.exe 127.0.0.1
```

Con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, creo que tenemos que hacerlo desde el mismo proyecto, puede ser? Existe alguna manera de ejecutar desde 2 archivos .cpp desde el mismo proyecto y a la vez?

Comment: En que es el proyecto? Digo con que lo construyes?

Comment: No se si no lo habia dicho, es en C++, y creo que era el mismo proyecto porque tenía so un archivo .h

Comment: Me refería a como y que herramientas usas para compilar el proyecto. Ejemplo make y gcc

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: Pues crea una solución con dos proyectos de tipo consola. Necesitas dos ejecutables, es la gracia de las comunicaciones :) cada proyecto como te explique en mi respuesta.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, haré lo que dices. En cuanto a lo de pasar el local host como argumento, en las propiedades, sabes de que puede ir?

Comment: Busca en las propiedades del proyecto cliente, hay una opción  para los argumentos de línea de comando.